# UserManager requires Two type Argument

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to add two factor authentication to my application but I get the following error related to `UserManager`:

`Mirosoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager<TUser,Tkey> requires two type argument`

Here is a screenshot of the relevant part of my code:

[image]

Comment: next time include your code the proper way instead of adding painted-over pictures please.